# How to find the list of country for a android app that is available for download

Tags: android, download

For iOS this site can find out the availability of the APP

http://www.georiot.com/using-georiot/itunes/test-your-links

For Android , is there any similar site can check the availability of the APP by country ?

*And I do not have access to the developer console, as I am not the owner of the app

Comment: what's wrong with this question ? why vote it down ?

Answer (score 0):

You can see that info in the Play Console when you publish your app... you can choose in which country you want it to be available...

Comment: If I am not the owner of the app, so I do not have access the play console. I am providing the library for other company to write their app.  For some reason of restriction. I need to find out which country the app is published

Comment: Sory but in that case I cannot help you... :(